# Trying to centre a fixed width rule and left aligned text in a Bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to centre an item in a Boostrap column that consists of a fixed width image (that is narrower than the column width) and some text under the image that is left aligned with the left edge of the rule (and NOT left aligned with the left edge of the Bootstrap column).

My code looks like this:

```css
.imgWidth {
  max-width:150px;
}
```

```html
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 text-center">    
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                 <div class="text-center"><img class="imgWidth" src="/assets/img/photo.jpg"></div>  
                  <div class="text-left">text under image</div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                 <div class="text-center"><img class="imgWidth" src="/assets/img/photo.jpg"></div>  
                  <div class="text-left">text under image</div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                 <div class="text-center"><img class="imgWidth" src="/assets/img/photo.jpg"></div>  
                  <div class="text-left">text under image</div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                 <div class="text-center"><img class="imgWidth" src="/assets/img/photo.jpg"></div>  
                  <div class="text-left">text under image</div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 text-center">         
            </div>
        </div>
```

This code centres the image in the column but the text, rather than being left aligned under the image, is left aligned with the column.

Is there are way to get the text left aligned with the image above? I have tried every possible combination of code that I can think of but with no success.

Comment: Just to say you do have two closing div's at the end of three used columns. Is that a mistake?

Comment: Yes that was a typo! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to add a class to the text divs in the columns and adding the max-width to them also as well as adding margin auto to the text div's too?

CSS:

```
.imgWidth, .someClass {
    max-width:150px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 text-center">    
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
             <div class="text-center"><img class="imgWidth" src="/assets/img/photo.jpg"></div>  
              <div class="text-left someClass">text under image</div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
             <div class="text-center"><img class="imgWidth" src="/assets/img/photo.jpg"></div> 
              <div class="text-left someClass">text under image</div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
             <div class="text-center"><img class="imgWidth" src="/assets/img/photo.jpg"></div> 
              <div class="text-left someClass">text under image</div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
             <div class="text-center"><img class="imgWidth" src="/assets/img/photo.jpg"></div> 
              <div class="text-left someClass">text under image</div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 text-center">         
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: A few items. 1) You can put the `margin: auto;` item up with the `.imgWidth, .someClass` CSS. 2) You can get rid of the `col-sm-12` in the top and bottom divs and just use the `col-xs-12` classes, as they'll work the same at any viewport width. http://jsfiddle.net/degoeym/g6038qeh/1/

Comment: Just tried that but unfortunately the text still left aligns with the column rather than the img

Comment: Good spot with the CSS, if the img is central anyway. And have altered the HTML, was just using OP's code to show where to put new classes

Comment: There you go! Another excellent solution. Thanks lee_gladding.

Comment: @lee_gladding I know you were just using OP's HTML, I just pointed it out because I'm like that.

Comment: @MattD yeah no worries honestly, best to get responses and code to the best they can be, appreciate it. To be honest I had already suggested a better way of doing this in a previous post by OP using bootstrap offsets and getting rid of the empty div's completely, which I don't think he was able to do before this post so mostly why I wasn't too worried anyway :)